# Matrix elements of four-quark operators

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, electroweak, effective-field-theory, weak-interaction

In weak interaction phenomenology, especially in strangeness changing processes, effective four-quark operators are used. Such as  $Q_1 = (\bar{s}_\alpha \gamma_\mu (1-\gamma_5) d_\alpha) (\bar{u}_\beta \gamma^\mu (1-\gamma_5) u_\beta)$ kind of operators, for example in [this](http://inspirehep.net/record/143977?ln=en), Eq.22, page no. 21. ($\alpha,\beta = 1,2,3 $ are color indices). I needed help in calculating the matrix elements of these operators, let's say, for the process $ \bar{s} \to \gamma^* d \to e^+ e^-$ through a quark-loop, here I have drawn a $u$-quark loop but it can be any quark $q$.

[image: Figure]

The problems that I am facing are:

1. It involves both spinor and color indices.
2. It's very different than calculations involving single kind of leptons where trace-technology is much simpler, but here we have different kinds of quarks.

Can anyone please provide answers or link to books or notes where similar calculations are done. For example, explicit cross-section calculations using Fermi's four-fermion operators, even this will be really helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Why was this closed? This is a simple reference request?

Comment: Voting to reopen because I'd love to see more questions like this one.

Comment: This kind of calculations are so ubiquitous in weak interaction phenomenology, a discussion will definitely help researchers in the related areas, I request to reopen the thread.